# Simple way to check neighbouring array

Tags: c, arrays, loops, syntax, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a program and need to check if two cells in a row are the same. I have my 5 by 5 2d array board full of characters that can either be x, y, z. Any advice on how I could do this. As of right now, I'm thinking about creating a condition and putting it into a loop

```
if(arr[0][0] == 'z' && arr[0][1] == 'z'{
    //replace with an a
}
```

If the neighbouring cells are the same, I want it to change to an a

Comment: why not `arr[0][0] == arr[0][1]` and use a loop to check for that

Comment: Please explain further. As your values are only x,y,z and number of columns in a row are 5, definitely there will be some cells having the same values

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes there will be 25 cells full of x, y and z but only the cells that are neighbouring need to change. so if the top row had y z x x y, the 2 xs will change.

Comment: do you want `z x x y` --> `z x z y` or `z y x y` ? or you do check when filling the data of board?

Comment: The latter, z x x y --> z y x y

Answer (score 1):

The condition in the loop should be something like

```
arr[i][j] == arr[i][j+1]
```

And be careful not to go out of the bounds of your array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
void compare( char array[5][5])
{
    int x,y;
    for(x=0;x<4;  x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<4;  y++)
        { 
            if (array[x][[y] == array[x][y+1] )
            {
                //do something
            }
            if (array[x][[y] == array[x+1][y] )
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

sorry for the bad format. I am working on my nokia c3-00 mobile phone and formatting is not simple

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create so as not to overlap with neighboring cells when creating the data of the board.
like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ROW 5
#define COL 5

char Board[ROW][COL];

void createBoard(void);

int main(void){
    srand(time(NULL));
    createBoard();
    return 0;
}

void swap(char *a, char *b){
    char tmp = *a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=tmp;
}

void createBoard(void){
    char letter[3] = {'x', 'y', 'z'};
    int i, j, k;
    for(i=0; i < ROW; ++i){
        for(j=0,k=3; j < COL; ++j){
            if(j!=0){
                k = 2;
                swap(strchr(letter, Board[i][j-1]), &letter[2]);
            }
            Board[i][j] = letter[rand()%k];
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i < ROW; i++){
        for(j=0; j < COL; j++){
            printf("%c ", Board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```